# Google Cloud Functions - Repository deployment - Reading Setting File

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

This might be more of a best practice question, but I am deploying a cloud function in GCloud via GitHub repo to multiple environments, each with their own secrets for database up that this cloud function will write to (elastic search). How do I get the function to access a settings file in their own respective environments? Using Node.js, FYI.

Comment: We had the same issue. We finished up with dedicated Jenkins CI. We setup two repos, one for configs and credentials files, and one for code. When build launched it's fetch both repos, mix-in into code files configs files and deploying it to destination GCF.

Answer (score 2):

I think we were able to figure this out, so posting for other people.

I found a handy little npm package called cloud-functions-runtime-config (looks like this guy also had a similar issue, but it took a certain google passphrase for me to find it, so hoping for more exposure!)

https://github.com/fredriks/cloud-functions-runtime-config

There is a tool available in beta called Runtime Configurator which is uses:

https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/runtime-configurator/

Once we set that up using the following:

`gcloud beta runtime-config configs create <CONFIG NAME>`

And created variables using:

`gcloud beta runtime-config configs variables set <VARIABLE NAME> <VARIABLE VALUE> --config-name <CONFIG NAME>`

Calling it was a piece of cake. Thanks random internet guy for solving my issue!